# How would you go about making a Simple RSS Feed URL Detecter Action Extension in iOS 8

Tags: ios, xml, swift, rss

Im trying to make a Basic RSS Reader with a Action Extension that will detect a RSS Feed URL (XML Based) from a Webpage like from Safari or other Web Browsers for iOS. But I Cant figure out how to program such thing I've got the UI Working and Basic Code ready to Plug the Data Need but just can't figure out how to Parse and Check for XML Based RSS Feed URLs on Webpages. I can't find a Tutorial on the Subject and I'm Writing it in Swift.

Action Extension Looks like This

[image]

Comment: Look at https://subtome.com as well because many sites support it! Plugging your reader in there should be relatively trivial!

Comment: So all i would need is to know the subtle api and connected it to the Action Extension of my iOS 8 Application